# Crystal Reports: how to have multiple groups at the same level?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'd like to have several groups in my report. Only one group should be shown, the other ones should be hidden depending on a variable which the report gets from calling application. The problem is that multiple reports are always built hierarchically. Is it possible to avoid it?

thx for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create group sections. In your section expert, right-click on the group and click on "Add Section Below". Now you will have a group header a and b. You can add as many group sections as you need (I've never come across a limitation) and then suppress them accordingly.

Hope that helps,

Chris

Comment: The groups inside the sections are nevertheless nested.

Comment: You could base your group on a formula: if variable = a then groupByFieldA else if variable = b then groupByFieldB.....

Comment: How can I define such actions as groupByFieldA or groupByFieldB?

Comment: ok, simple example: you have a table (table) that contains 4 fields (field1, field2, field3, field4. You have your variable. If the value of the variable is 1, then you want to group by field 1, if the variable is 2 then you want to group by field 2, and so on. So you create a formula: if variable = 1 then table.field1 else if variable = 2 then table.field2..... Then you create your group by using Report -> Group Expert and choosing the formula to group by.

Comment: The last step of your explanation: Do you mean the check box "Use a formula as group sort order"?

Comment: I need 3 groups. Does it mean that the formula should be set for each group?

Comment: No, you said that you need 3 groups but don't want them nested. You also want to show the group based on a variable. So you create the formula the way I explained and the formula becomes the group. So the report will only show one group depending on the value of the variable. If that is not what you want then you need to rephrase your question.

Comment: That's right, I meant I need grouping on 1 of 3 columns dynamically. So I need to add only one group or no group at all? But if there's no group, I have nothing to add the formula to.

Comment: The formula IS the group. You have ONE group, which is the formula. In Crystal Reports on the menu bar, click REPORT, then GROUP EXPERT. In AVAILABLE FIELDS, double click your formula so it gets moved to GROUP BY. Click OK. That sets the group value to your formula.

Comment: I've understood at last! Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Actually directly it's not possible to have several seperated groups in single report.
In crystal report, if you want to have two different group, then you have only one option:
1> create one group
2> after that create different sub-reports and in sub-reports insert groups.

Eg:

you have to create two groups based on name and id, then
create one group with name
and create one sub-report having group in it with id.

This will definitely solve the mentioned problem.